# How i can save progress view animation state when entering background, and restore it when app is active?

Tags: swift, uikit

So basically, I have UIProgressView, I animate it like that:

```
func startProgressAnimation() {
    self.progressView.progress = 1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
        self.progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
    } completion: { [weak self] finished in
        if finished {
            self?.delegate?.scrollToNextStory()
        }
    }
}

func resumeProgressAnimation() {
    let layer = progressView.layer
    let pausedTime = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1
    layer.timeOffset = 0
    layer.beginTime = 0
    let timeSincePause = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause

}

func pauseProgressAnimation() {
    let layer = progressView.layer
    let pausedTime = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

when app is active everything working fine, on entering background i called pause function, on active i call resume, but it didn't work, animation completely removed. **How i can save current animation state? and restore it?**

**Second Question is How can I reset animation halfway, and replay it?** Now I'm doing something like:

```
func resetProgress() {
    progressView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { layer in layer.removeAllAnimations() }

    progressView.layer.timeOffset = 0
    progressView.layer.beginTime = 0
    progressView.layer.speed = 1

    progressView.setProgress(0, animated: false)
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the idea:

1. Calculate the end date at the initialization point: for example if you want the progress view to complete in 5 seconds, the end date would be now + 5 seconds
2. Start the animation.
3. On entering background, set the progress to the elapsed time and remove all animations. You can calculate it using the current time and the endDate.
4. (optional) On entering foreground, set the progress to the elapsed time without animation. It will feels like the progress goes on even in the background.
5. Calculate the remaining duration.
6. Start another animation with the new duration if needed.

Comment: sorry, can you provide an example? how can I know hoy much progress i already have when entring background? I can get remaining time, but not progress.

Comment: Imagine the total of 5 seconds (end date == 00:00:05). 3 seconds later (00:00:03) you are leaving the app. so (endDate - now == 2 seconds). So if 5 will be 100% then 2 will be?

Comment: hmm, makes sense, i'll do some proportion thing

Answer (score 1):

You can handle with timer in this case. Initialize a timer count with 1, whenever app will enter background, invalidate timer, then init again when app becomes active. Notice: stop the loop when progress reaches its maximum value. Check out the example code below:

```swift
    private var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       initTimer()
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onAppDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onAppWillResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func onAppDidBecomeActive() {
        initTimer()
    }
    
    @objc private func onAppWillResignActive() {
        invalidateTimer()
    }
    
    private func initTimer() {
        guard timer == nil else { return }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(startProgressAnimation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    private func invalidateTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    
    @objc private func startProgressAnimation() {
        guard timer != nil else { return }
        guard progressView.progress < 1.0 else { invalidateTimer(); return }
        progressView.progress += 0.2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
            self.progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
        } completion: { finished in
            if finished && self.progressView.progress == 1.0 {
                self.delegate?.scrollToNextStory()
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note that timers are so expensive. Try to avoid them as much as possible. Also, timers doesn't work in the background

Comment: it's going to call completion each second, i need to call when progress animation completed

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin I edited the answer, added a condition on completion when progress reached 1.0, take a look.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thanks for your comment about the expensive object. My solution is to add and remove the timer every time when app goes from foreground to background and vice versa, there is no need to handle in background.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pause and resume UIView animations by manipulating the underlying Core Animations that they create, but it is tricky and not well documented.

You should instead rewrite your animation to use a UIViewPropertyAnimator.

It makes pausing animations and setting them to an arbitrary progress value easy.

When your app is suspended, you'd record the animator's `fractionComplete` value and plus the animation. When your app returns to the foreground you'd restore the `fractionComplete` and resume the animation.

I have a demo project on Github called "[**UIVIew PropertyAnimator test**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test.git)" that demonstrates pausing and resuming animations. It doesn't deal with suspending and resuming an app, but it should give you the basic idea on how to pause and resume animations using `UIVIewPropertyAnimator`.

Comment: should I animate progress property of UIProgressView?

Comment: The animator operates on animatable properties of views, such as the frame, center, alpha, and transform properties.